# What kind of owner and user to defined when creating Sql server DB for web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create db and I need to select owner.
My db will serve aspnet web site and I wonder which owner will be safe to defined for this db ?

With what kind of user I need to connect from my site (the connection string )
do I need to create special user to connect the db or I can just set the any user i like?any special configuration/security ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate account for website access and grant it the minimum access needed to do what it needs.  Ideally just execute access to the stored procedures used by the site and no direct access to tables.  The owner can be any suitable user.

It is easier to change the access of several users than to try to separate a shared user later.